# find the manager of sales employee

Tags: mysql, sql

my table is 'DESIGNATION'

```
ID    ||    DEPT_ID     ||      E_NAME       ||      DESIGNATION
1     ||     12         ||        A          ||       EMPLOYEE
2     ||     12         ||        B          ||       MANAGER
3     ||     12         ||        C          ||       EMPLOYEE
4     ||     14         ||        D          ||       MANGER
5     ||     14         ||        E          ||       EMPLOYEE
6     ||     14         ||        F          ||       EMPLOYEE
```

I want the manager name through their DEPT_NAME....

Mean result will look like

```
ID    ||    DEPT_ID     ||      E_NAME       ||      DESIGNATION  ||   MANAGER
1     ||     12         ||        A          ||       EMPLOYEE    ||    B
2     ||     12         ||        B          ||       MANAGER     ||    B
3     ||     12         ||        C          ||       EMPLOYEE    ||    B
4     ||     14         ||        D          ||       MANGER      ||    D
5     ||     14         ||        E          ||       EMPLOYEE    ||    D
6     ||     14         ||        F          ||       EMPLOYEE    ||    D
```

My query is

```
SELECT `ID`,`DEPT_ID`,`ENAME`,`DESIGNATION`,
    (select `ENAME` from `DESIGNATION` where 
        (select `E_NAME` from `DESIGNATION` where 
            (SELECT `DEPT_ID` FROM `DESIGNATION` WHERE `DESIGNATION` = 'EMPLOYEE')
            =
            (SELECT `DEPT_ID` FROM `DESIGNATION` WHERE `DESIGNATION` = 'MANAGER') and `DESIGNATION`='MANAGER')
    AS MANAGER
from `DESIGNATION`
```

but its not working...

Comment: You have a QUADRUPLE-nested subquery and you expect it to work?

Comment: i don't know...please help me...

Comment: So B and D are manager of themselve?

Comment: See JOINs. If you're still struggling, consider providing a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

You just need a [`JOIN` operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29). This is a basic concept when working with database. You should take some time reading about it.

Something like that?

```
SELECT A.*, B.E_NAME 
   FROM DESIGNATION AS A, DESIGNATION AS B
   WHERE B.DESIGNATION = "MANAGER" 
     AND A.DEPT_ID = B.DEPT_ID
```

Or using *explicit* `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT A.*, B.E_NAME 
   FROM DESIGNATION AS A JOIN DESIGNATION AS B USING (DEPT_ID)
   WHERE B.DESIGNATION = "MANAGER"
```

---

**EDIT:**
If you could have multiple managers, you could use the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate functions with explicit group by `E_NAME` (assuming this is an unique key):

```
SELECT A.*, GROUP_CONCAT(B.E_NAME) 
   FROM DESIGNATION AS A, DESIGNATION AS B
   WHERE B.DESIGNATION = "MANAGER" 
     AND A.DEPT_ID = B.DEPT_ID
   GROUP BY(A.E_NAME)
```

Comment: I would prefer using `JOIN DESIGNATION B USING (DEPT_ID)`, as this should make better use of indexes.

Comment: What if more than one manager happens to be in designation column?

Comment: @Kolink I _think_ the SQL query optimizer is "smart enough" to produce the exact same sequence of operations with both syntax. But if you prefer ;)

Comment: @peterm Well, the problem does not state they could have multiple managers for the same dept. :P Of course, if it is the case you will have all the lines "duplicated" -- one time for each manager.

Comment: @peterm You could handle the "multiple manager" case by using `GROUP_CONCAT`. I-ve edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Old-school join syntax - sorry - but your sub queries don't make much sense.

```
Select d.ID,
       d.DEPT_ID,
       d.E_NAME, 
       d.DESIGNATION
       m.MANAGER
from   designation d, 
       designation m
where  d.dept_id   =   m.dept_id
and    m.designation = 'MANAGER'
```

Comment: I would use '=' instead of 'LIKE' though.

Comment: @sam I agree. Although I wonder if MySQL optimises "like string w/o wildcards" to "= string"

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a better job for whatever server-side script you're running. For example, in PHP, you can do this:

```php
$managers = []; // array() before version 5.4
$employees = []; // see above comment
$query = "SELECT * FROM `DESIGNATION`";
$result = mysql_query($query); // adjust according to extension of choice
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // same as previous comment
    $employees[] = $row;
    if( $row['DESIGNATION'] == "MANAGER") $managers[$row['DEPT_ID']] = $row['E_NAME'];
}
foreach($employees as $i=>$e) {
    $employees[$i]['MANAGER'] = $managers[$e['DEPT_ID']] ?: "Nobody";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple JOIN will help, I prefer an explicit JOIN instead of the implicit comma notation:

```
SELECT `ID`,`DEPT_ID`,`E_NAME`,`DESIGNATION`, m.e_name, AS `MANAGER`
FROM `DESIGNATION` e
INNER JOIN `DESIGNATION` m 
 ON e.dept_id = m.dept_id 
WHERE m.designation = 'MANAGER'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't we simply do this, in more simpler way ?

```
SELECT ID,DEPT_ID,ENAME,DESIGNATION,
case 
when DEPT_ID=12 then 'B'
when DEPT_ID=14 then 'D'
end "MANAGER"
from DESIGNATION
```

Comment: Ouch. Correct but not very helpful answer.

Comment: C'mon. Do you really want to know why this is not helpful? What happens when you get entries with a DEPT_ID not in (12,14)? How do you write your query when you have hundreds of different DEPT_IDs?

Comment: ok.. in that case, I agree. But, OP has to put data like that, OP simply put raw data and said I have this and I want this. Nevertheless, thanks for your correction.:)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT t.id
       ,t.dept_id
       ,t.e_name
       ,t.designation
       ,ta.e_name As Manager   FROM Table1 t   JOIN (SELECT e_name,dept_id 
          FROM Table1 WHERE designation  = 'MANAGER' 
          GROUP BY dept_id,e_name) ta    ON ta.dept_id = t.dept_id
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/765d6/2)**